# How can I make the size of an array dependent on a constructor parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, constructor, static

In the *incorrect* code below of a queue, I'm trying to make the struct 'bar' hold an array of length `ARR_SIZE`.  I want this variable to be dependent on the parameter I give it during it's construction.
So in one instance when I construct a `foo` I would like the array within the struct to be a length of `8` or in another case I would like to make it an array of `1000`.  How can this be done?

I know that you can make `ARR_SIZE` a `static` variable, but wouldn't that mean the size of the array is the same for every instance of the class `foo`?
Is there a way to make this parameter different for each instance of `foo`?

```
class foo
{
private:
    int ARR_SIZE;
public:
    foo();
    foo(int arr_size);
    ~foo();
    struct bar {
        int arrInt[ARR_SIZE];
        bar* next;
    };
    void enqueue(int a);
    int dequeue();
};


foo::foo()
{
    ARR_SIZE = 8;
}

foo::foo(int arr_size)
{
    ARR_SIZE = arr_size;
}
```

Comment: You can do so using `std::vector<int>` instead. As you're doing it, it won't work.

Comment: There are no VLAs in standard C++. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: if the size can always be computed at compile-time, it can be a template parameter for the class

Comment: Where are you instantiating `bar`?

Comment: I would eventually instantiate 'bar' when I run 'enqueue()'.  The code just hasn't been shown.

Comment: Are you allowed to use pointer instead of array?

Comment: @Sniper Sure why not? Is there something you want to suggest?

Comment: @Sniper Please don't start to suggest managing that array dynamically with `new` and `delete`. That's what `std::vector` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw arrays cannot change their size at runtime in C++. That's what the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) class was made for in the c++ standrd library.

Change your class to

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo() : arr_size_(8) {}
    foo(size_t arr_size) : arr_size_(arr_size) {}
    ~foo();
    struct bar {
        std::vector<int> arrInt; // <<< use std::vector
        bar* next;
    };
    void enqueue(int a);
    int dequeue();
private:
    size_t arr_size_;
};
```

Now whenever you need to instantiate a new `bar` object you can write

```
void foo::enqueue(int a) {
    bar b{ arrInt(arr_size_), nullptr };
    // or
    bar* b = new bar{ arrInt(arr_size_), nullptr };
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I understand arrays can't change their size at runtime. I just wanted to create a class that can create arrays of different lengths, essentially create a "chunk-list" that uses arrays of a different length for each instance of the class that is created.  I'm just experimenting with data structures, which is why I avoided using vectors.

Comment: @Chan There's no reason to _avoid vectors_, as mentioned that's what they're made for. Another way is to provide the size as a class template parameter as _@M.M._ mentioned.

Comment: @tobi303 Well, the array or vector appears in the inner struct.

Comment: doh, sorry, overlooked that, should take more coffee instead of writing stupid comments ;)

Comment: @tobi303 More coffee is always a good decision. My avatar suggests that clearly ;-)